# Keras LSTM: Getting TypeError : 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer on train_on_batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, typeerror, lstm

I am trying to write my first LSTM with Keras and i'm stucking. 
That are my training data structure: x_data = [1265, 12] y_data = [1265, 3]

x_data example: `[102.7, 100.69, 103.39, 99.6, 319037.0, 365230.0, 1767412, 102.86, 13.98]`

My Model looks like the following:

```
    self.model = Sequential()
    self._opt_cells = 12

    self.model.add(LSTM(units = self._opt_cells, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (1265, 12)))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    self.model.add(LSTM(units = self._opt_cells, return_sequences = True))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    self.model.add(LSTM(units = self._opt_cells, return_sequences = True))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    self.model.add(LSTM(units = self._opt_cells))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    self.model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))

    self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This line throwing the error:

```
        cost = self.model.train_on_batch(np.reshape(x_data, [x_data[0], x_data[1], 1]), np.reshape(y_data, [y_data[0], y_data[1], 1]))
```

I have no idea why i am receiving the error: TypeError : 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Look at the np.reshape function here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

It says:
numpy.reshape(a, newshape, order='C')

The second argument ('newshape') is the shape you wish to convert your array to. In your case, the shape you are converting to is 'x_data[1]' and 'y_data[1]', which is probably a float. As I don't know how your data set looks like, I can not tell you more than this. So, take a closer look at the documentation of the np.reshape function()

Comment: Ohh yes thats my fault. I have changed that line of code to: 
            cost = self.model.train_on_batch(np.reshape(x_data, [x_data[0], x_data[1], 1]), np.reshape(y_data, [y_data[0], y_data[1], 1])) But i ran into an similiar issue: TypeError : 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: The second input should be a tuple, not a list. Try replacing  [x_data[0], x_data[1],1] by  (x_data[0], x_data[1],1).